# Create TypeScript declaration file for EmberJS

Tags: ember.js, typescript

I'm trying to create declaration file for EmberJS.
I try to just create enough declaration to create the starter-kit application.

```
var App = Em.Application.create();

App.MyView = Em.View.extend({
  mouseDown: function() {
    window.alert("hello world!");
  }
});
```

I try several things like create module call Em and create interfaces inside of it but I didn't manage to get it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your example, this adds typing around the items you are using. I have made assumptions, such as `Application.create()` returns an `Application` - you can adjust the example as you require.

```
declare module Em {
    class Application {
        static create() : Application;
        MyView: View;
    }

    class View {
        static extend(extender: {}) : View;
    }
}

var App = Em.Application.create();

App.MyView = Em.View.extend({
  mouseDown: function() {
    window.alert("hello world!");
  }
});
```

Comment: I didn't realize I can put classes in the declaration file. Is there documentation about .d.ts files because the TypeScript docs have 4 lines about it. Thank you

Comment: @IdoRan You might wanna check [this](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) out. It still doesn't have Ember/Handlebars/Ember-Data (I'm actually creating a few definitions for them and should send PR soon) trio but there's a bunch of useful definitions already.

Comment: Hopefully I'll be able to have high quality declaration file to put in your wonderful repository. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating a definition file for the purpose of understanding, or if you are just trying to create an ember definition then you might want to check out this github project:

[typescript definitions for a bunch of popular libraries](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped)

It was a huge help for me, helping me to wrap my head around the type definition gymnastics which are required to create a useful library type definition  (mostly due to the widely varying javascript api definition/usage styles that exist).

Alternatively, if you just want an ember definition, just snag the file :)

Comment: Thank you, you made a huge progress in the last few days. I will build on top of your declaration file, together we can get much further.